# Apache serving content via smb

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, linux-networking, network-share

So basically, I want to host a network smb share on my Redhat 6.2 Apache httpd server.  My basic configuration is outlined below, however, I keep getting errors.

So my basic configuration

```
/mnt/ShareDocs -> network \\smb\share
```

/etc/fstab

`//smb/shared /mnt/ShareDocs cifs defaults,wsize=65535,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.creds 0 0`

Apache 2.2 (httpd.conf)

```
<Directory "/var/www/help">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /help /var/www/help
```

tail -f error_log gives me -> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/help

So I take the symbolic link out of the equation, and go directly at the mount point.  I change my directory to ...

```
<Directory "/mnt/ShareDocs"> ...
```

I then get a different error message that says..

[error] [client ip] (13)Permission denied: access to /help/Manual.pdf denied

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What distro is this ?

Comment: @Iain I noticed that I didn't supply that piece of information, I just updated my question.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled ?

Comment: @Iain yes  >sestatus --> SELinux status: enabled

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will quit likely be due be due to SELinux.

First set SELinux into permissive mode

```
setenforce 0
```

and then test your setup. If it now works then SELinux is proved to be the culprit.

You can use the tools available to figure out what needs changing.

```
grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
```

or look at

```
grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow
```

and take appropriate action.

Don't forget to set SELinux back to enforcing

```
setenforce 1
```

Disabling SELinux isn't a good solution.